# JQuery Load and missing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, load

I have a webpage containing lots of php and JQuery code. From this webpage, I use the Load function to open popup window and load webpages inside it.

I noticed that, randomly, I get some console error about "typos" in the code when opening the webpage, like "var foo 10" instead of "var foo = 10". Weird thing is, what's really in the webpage is "var foo = 10".

When I check the post performed when the load function is fired, I can see it load the page with missing/modified data randomly, causing errors.

I tried to place all the javascript code from the loaded page in the main page using the live() of JQuery for firing events, it tend to reduce the number of time I'm getting the issue, but from time to time I'm getting this strange behavior.

I also tried to delay the load function with some kind of throttle, but it hasn't changed anything.

Any idea how I could troubleshoot that ?

Thanks !

Comment: First thing to do is to look at the network tab of the debugger in your browser and see if the data is coming over the wire in a corrupted fashion.  That will tell you whether to focus your search on the server side or client side.

Comment: I didn't noticed anything strange on the network tab of firebug, everything seems to load just fine. Any other ideas ?

Comment: You'll have to show us your actual code then that reproduces the problem.  If the issue is on the client, then some code somewhere is trying to "process" the javascript and is missing it up.